# Can The REST API be used to create/edit plugins and themes?

Tags: plugins, rest-api

I'm trying to use chatgpt to create an entire website start to finish, the only problem I've run into is that I'm not sure how I would edit/add plug-ins and files/folders via the REST API. I have a plug-in with dedicated endpoints for each task, but I don't know how to create new folders/files from the plug-in itself. I know I'm not the most informed but I can't find the answer elsewhere

Comment: WordPress provides the [`WP_Filesystem`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_filesystem/) API (and its related APIs) to interface with your site's filesystem.

Comment: I don't mean to be churlish but... ...have you asked ChatGPT?  ;-)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.